# fields.E300: Field defines a relation with model, which is either not installed, or is abstract

Tags: django, python-3.x

Yes, I know this is repeated and I have gone through other questions but nothing works for me. I have just started learning Django and I am getting this error while migrating two models with circular import. I have no idea what i can do to  solve this as I have tried most of possible solutions I have found. I guess maybe I am doing something wrong which raises this error. Please, guide me if that is the case.

### User Model

```
class UserCustom(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.TextField()
    last_list = models.ForeignKey(TaskList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'UserCustom'

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

### TaskList Model

```
class TaskList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey('user.UserCustom', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'listtask.apps.ListTaskConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

> Note: I do not want to use default user table of Django admin.

Comment: Did you tried changing `'user.UserCustom'` to `UserCustom` in `TaskList`'s `ForeignKey` ?

Comment: if i do not write it like 'app_label.model' will it be fine? I guess it would throw error of model not found.

Comment: Just do what I said. And remove  the whole `Meta` class in `UserCustom`

Comment: did already doesn't work as both the models are in different apps, so u have to give app label otherwise it will look for the model in same app

Comment: well then you can simply import the model from the other app into the app where your `TaskList` is defined like this : `from app_name.models import UserCustom` and then do what I said.

Comment: you are writing `'user.UserCustom'` but i think it should be `'users.UserCustom'`, you are missing a `s`

Comment: Solved  it removed the label and provided app name instead of label, thanks for the help

Comment: yes @VaibhavVishal got it, it was a typo, sorry for wasting time.